# UiAutomator 2.0 Equivalent of scrollIntoView

Tags: android, android-testing, android-uiautomator

I'm starting to use UiAutomator in a project I'm working on and wanted to start using the latest and greatest UiAutomator 2.0. I know that in earlier versions of UiAutomator you could scroll through a list searching for an item like so:

```
device.findObject(new UiScrollable(new UiSelector().scrollable(true)).scrollIntoView(new UiSelector().text("Search Text")));
```

Although this is possible in the newest version of the library, it is deprecated. I'd like to use the non-deprecated parts of the library to accomplish this. I've searched for examples far and wide and have been unable to find anything.

To summarize what I want, I want to do something similar to `scrollIntoView` (documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/uiautomator/UiScrollable.html#scrollIntoView(android.support.test.uiautomator.UiSelector))) using the result of `device.findObject(By.scrollable(true))`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use getChildByText

```
UiObject **getChildByText** (UiSelector childPattern, 
                String text, 
                boolean allowScrollSearch)
```

Searches for a child element in the present scrollable container. The search first looks for a child element that matches the selector you provided, then looks for the text in its children elements. If both search conditions are fulfilled, the method returns a {@ link UiObject} representing the element matching the selector (not the child element in its subhierarchy containing the text).

You can find other methods on https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/uiautomator/UiScrollable.html

Answer (score 0):

```
scrollObject.getChildByText("Search Text");
```

this command automatically scrolls to your text object if it is not in view.

Answer (score 0):

`UiObject2` has a `scrollUntil()` method which you can give a `Condition<T,U>` to and will return the matching object if found.

```kotlin
val searchText = device.findObject(By.scrollable(true))
  .scrollUntil(Direction.Down, Until.findObject(By.text("Search Text")
```

Comment: Worth to mention that `scrollUntil` is only available from `UIAutomator Version 2.3.0-alpha03`.

Comment: And the alpha lib requires API 34  compiled version 'androidx.test.uiautomator:uiautomator:2.3.0-alpha04' requires libraries and applications that depend on it to compile against version 34'